# Можно ли интегрировать скомпилированные модули QT в проект на PyQT?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt5

Чисто теоретический вопрос: передо мной стоит задача разработать графический интерфейс, в котором будет некое количество разделенных окон посредством QDockWidget. Я хотел бы реализовать его на PyQT6. И у меня возник вопрос, можно ли поместить в эти виджеты уже скомпилированные модули с графическим интерфейсом на QT, которые написаны на C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы использовать скомпилированный модуль C++ в PyQt, вам нужно будет использовать QtCore.QObject.connect метод для подключения сигналов и слотов модуля C ++ к вашему приложению PyQt. Это позволит вам обмениваться данными между модулем C ++ и вашим PyQt-кодом. Затем вы можете использовать этот QtWidgets.QDockWidget класс для создания разделенных окон в вашем графическом интерфейсе и добавления модуля C++ к этим виджетам.

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию

Comment: А можете привести пример как используется QtCore.QObject.connect? И каким образом в него передается объект модуля?

Comment: Поискал на просторах примеры, нашёл такой код: https://pastebin.com/6JpgmfpA
Тут реализация путём подгрузки QLibrary, может поможет

Comment: Благодарю, это будет полезно

Comment: я попробовал протестировать это и у меня возникла проблема, после cppmodule.load(), я проверяю успешность загрузки cppmodule.isloaded(), и он возвращает False. Файл, к которому я указываю путь должен быть определенного типа? ps Тестировал на примере программы qtpass.

Comment: Указал путь: /usr/bin/qtpass. И это не сработало